# Declaring multiple route parameters for one segment

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-routing, angular-router, angular8

Going straight into the problem. Is there a way to declare multiple route parameters for one segment like the route below:

**The Routes:**

```
{
    path: 'planlist/:departure_:destination/:date',
    component: ReservationComponent
},
```

**In ReservationComponent**:

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
/* ... */
console.log(this.route.snapshot.params)

/* Output */
{
    "departure_:destination": "tokyo_newyork",
    "date": "2019-09-27"
}
```

**My expectation for the output:**

```
/* Output */
{
    "departure": "tokyo",
    "destination": "newyork",
    "date": "2019-09-27"
}
```

Is there any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. You can do it using the queryParams feature.

For that, you need to correct the path to:

```
path: 'planlist',
```

You send all the variables in the queryParams object as follows:

```
router.navigate(['planlist'], { queryParams: { departure, destination, date } });
```

And the catch them like this:

```
 this.route
     .queryParamMap
         .pipe(
             map(params => params.getAll()  || [])
         ).subscribe((params) => {
             if (!!params.length) {
                 this.planlistVars= params;
             }
         }).unsubscribe();
```

The key is **queryParamMap**, you can search more on Google or the official website of angular.
https://angular.io/api/router/ParamMap

Answer (score 0):

Just a small problem in your route. Modify it like this,

```
{
    path: 'planlist/:departure/:destination/:date',
    component: ReservationComponent
}
```

If you are routing from TS,

```
this.router.navigate(['planlist', departure, destination, date]);
```

Or from HTML,

```
routerLink="/planlist/{{departure}}/{{destination}}/{{date}}"
```

Comment: As my question title: Declare **multiple route parameters** in **one segment/fragment** my friend. Not multiple **segments/fragments**

Comment: @InOrderToLive Thats exactly what it does. **departure**, **destination** and **date** will become the parameters in **planlist** route. What your problem was that you merged **departure** and **destination** with an underscore.

Comment: And i am asking if there is a solution for this :))

Comment: @InOrderToLive Yeah. Did you try with my solution? It does meet your exact requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. The first thing you need to correct is the way to capture the variables using the path:
You've got:

```
path: 'planlist/:departure_:destination/:date',
```

The correct way is:

```
path: 'planlist/:departure/:destination/:date',
```

The second thing you should do is call the method as follows:

```
router.navigate(['planlist', departure, destination, date]);
```

And to capture the value of the variables:

```
const departure= this.route.snapshot.params['departure'];
const destination= this.route.snapshot.params['destination'];
const date= this.route.snapshot.params['date'];
```

Comment: As my question title: Declare **multiple route parameters** in **one segment/fragment** my friend. **Not multiple segments/fragments**